# Wrap comma-delimited lists

Tags: vim

I often use `gq$` to wrap a line in Vim.

For example, if I have `set textwidth=80` as my only line in `.vimrc`, then

```
option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8, option9, option10, option11
```

wraps to

```
option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8, option9, 
option10, option11
```

However, if I want to wrap a comma-delimited list (without spaces), this command does not work, because Vim considers this line as a single word:

```
option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6,option7,option8,option9,option10,option11
```

Whereas desired output is:

```
option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6,option7,option8,option9,
option10,option11
```

How can I allow Vim to wrap by splitting a line on commas? I didn't see anything immediately in `:help fo-table` that is relevant to my case.

Comment: This might involve writing your own `'formatexpr'` function. FYI, slightly faster to do `gqq` than `gq$`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use [Par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/).  It's the best program for reflowing text hands down, but you have to really like abstractions to digest the manual.  My cheat sheet for it:

- set the environment variable `PARINIT`:

  ```
  export PARINIT='grTbEiq B=.,!?_A_a Q=_s>:|'
  ```
- in my `vimrc`:

  ```
  set equalprg=par\ s0\ 72
  set formatprg=par\ s0\ 72

  function! s:FormatPar()
      let old_format = &formatprg
      let textwidth = &textwidth > 0 ? &textwidth : 72
      let &formatprg = 'par s0 ' . textwidth . (v:count > 0 ? 'h1p' . v:count : '')
      normal }{gq}
      normal }
      let &formatprg = old_format
  endfunc

  nnoremap <silent> <F2> :<C-u>silent! call <SID>FormatPar()<CR>
  ```

With that <kbd>F2</kbd> re-formats the current paragraph, and using it with a count adds a hanging indent (that is <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> formats the paragraph with a hanging indent of 4).

It works very well for email messages, comments in code, and the like.  It also has no problem with dealing with lists like above.

Comment: This answer is helpful but I'm interested in pure vim solutions as I don't have par on my system (or the ability to install it).